# Suppose $x$ is an odd function and let $h = f \circ g$. Is h always an odd function?

Tags: calculus

I have to be honest here, I tried doing it but I still don't get it and the answer key confused me even more for this matter.

So,according to answer key, **h** is even if **f** is even and **g** are odd. The answer the book gives for this scenario is this:

$$h(-x)=f(g(-x))=f(-g(x))=-f(g(x))=h(x)$$

I understand that in in order for function to be even it has to look like this:$$h(-x)=h(x)$$
HOWEVER, can someone explain to me what the middle part means, very confused?

(f(g(-x))=f(-g(x))=-f(gx)

Comment: If $f$ is even, then $f(-g(x))=f(g(x))$.

Comment: How come you write f(-g(x))=-f(gx) and not (f(g(-x))=f(-g(x))=-f(gx)?

Comment: what is $x$ in the title?

Comment: If the explanation that someone gave you includes the equation $f(-g(x))=-f(g(x))$, then the explanation is at best confusing, quite bad exposition.

Comment: It's the answer key given by my teacher's solution of textbook. I just don't understand the middle part.

Comment: The $f(g(-x))=f(-g(x))$ part is OK. It is the next equality which is not good.

Comment: @AndréNicolas : by not good you mean wrong??

Comment: Yes, unless the writer had some strange proof by contradiction in mind. In that case it is just very poor exposition.

Comment: It's going to take me a while to understand the answers, rereading answers slowly right now

Comment: Wait, if $f$ is even how come $f(-g(x)) = -f(g(x))$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$g(x)=-x;f(x)=x^2\Rightarrow f(g(x))=???$

Is this $f\circ g$ odd??

Coming to your question,

Read $$h(-x)=f(g(-x))=f(-g(x))=-f(g(x))=h(x)$$ as
$$h(-x)=f(g(-x))=f(-g(x))=f(g(x))=h(x)$$

Comment: I udnerstand your exmaple, but I don't get the formal approach the book took to this. Can you explain what this means and why it is put in middle? (f(g(-x))=f(-g(x))=-f(gx)

Comment: @user3718584 : see my edit...

Answer (score 1):

*Definition of odd and even functions :*
*A function f is odd if $f(-x)=-f(x), \forall x\in D(f)$ and even if $f(-x)=f(x), \forall x\in D(f)$.*

*$f(x)=x^4$ and $g(x)=x^3$. Then $f(g(x))=f(x^3)=x^{12}$ which is even. This serves as a counter example*

Answer (score 1):

Let $g$ be the odd function given by $g(x)=x$. Let $f(x)=x+1$. Then $f(g(x))=x+1$.

Note that the function $h(x)=x+1$ is not odd. For $h(-x)=-x+1$, and in general this is not equal to $-(x+1)$.

By the way, $h(x)$ is not even either.

Comment: I think it would be better to accept an answer that more directly addresses your concerns. I only dealt with those casually in comments.